# Redirecting URL

Tags: asp.net

http://Test.com/ProjectB/Login.aspx

http://Test.com/ProjectA/Login.aspx

In above URL’s, ProjectA, ProjectB, ProjectC, are different projects, but they are under
Same folder under Test.com. Here in above all URL we maintain session in a cookie for period of 1 hr.The issue is when I am working in one project in my system e.g. When I am working in "http://Test.com/ProjectB/Login.aspx"

If I change the Project name in the above URL, i.e. ProjectB to ProjectA then ProjectA gets working from the same page where I was previously working in ProjectB. [actually it should get log out but that’s not happening]